# Establish VPN connection using Powershell script

Tags: vpn, powershell, script

I have already set up a VPN connection on a client computer and i want to write a PowerShell script to connect to the VPN connection to prompt username and passowrd at logon. So i have written:

> Set-VpnConnection -Name "Work VPN" -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2
>   -DnsSuffix paris.pri -ServerAddress 192.168.100.15 -TunnelType Pptp

Unfortunately this is not working so i am searching for solution everywhere and i see use "rasdial" to connect to VPN connection. However i need to write a powershell script to deploy it via GPO at logon.

Comment: when you run that in ps, what happens?

Comment: ASG - In looking over the [Set-VpnConnection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554823(v=wps.630).aspx)... I see the section named **-UseWinlogonCredential<Boolean>** and it states. ***"Indicates whether to use Windows logon credentials. Specify a value of $True to use MSCHAPv2 or EAP-MSCHAPv2 as the authentication method and use Windows logon credentials automatically when connecting with the VPN connection profile."***. Therefore since you are using MSChapv2 I think this may be relevant to your problem. Give it a whirl and tag me back as `@` followed by my username on your status

Comment: @McDonald's Thanks i will keep you informed.